# Spark Streaming : Write Data to HDFS by reading from one HDFSdir to another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to use spark streaming in reading data from one HDFS location to another

Below is my code snippet on spark-shell

But I couldn't see the files created on HDFS output directory 
Can some point point how to load the files on HDFS

```
  scala> sc.stop()

  scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

  scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming

  scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.{StreamingContext,Seconds}

  scala> val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("files_word_count")

  scala> val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(10))

  scala> val DF = ssc.textFileStream("/user/cloudera/streamingcontext_dir")
  scala> val words_freq = DF.flatMap(x=>(x.split(" "))).map(y=>(y,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

  scala>    words_freq.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/streamingcontext_dir2")

  scala> ssc.start()
```

I have placed files on HDFS "/user/cloudera/streamingcontext_dir" and created another directory "/user/cloudera/streamingcontext_dir2" for seeing the files written

But I couldn't see the files in the output directory
Can someone point what's wrong here ?

Thanks
Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making use of RDD here and not the entire DStream perhaps:

```
words_freq.foreachRDD(rdd => 
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/streamingcontext_dir2")
```

Comment: Glad that it helped @SumitPawar request you to kindly mark the answer as accepted in that case (green check mark) as it may help other users who face the same issue.